# How to display attribute of an attribute in table - Java

Tags: java, jpa

I am attempting to display my data in a table, one attribute "Model" has attributes I would like to display in the table, below is an attempt

```
public void drawTable() throws Exception{

   try{
   List<PartsItem> ava = dm.getItemRepository().getAvailable();
   ItemSerial.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Item, String>("serialNumber"));
   ModelName.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Item, String>("model"));
   ObservableList<PartsItem> avai1 = FXCollections.observableArrayList(ava);       
   Available_DisplayTable.setItems(avai1); 
   }
   catch (Exception ex) {
       Logger.getLogger(PartsController.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
   }
```

The "model" attribute is of type Model, and in Model I have name in String and getters for it.

```
public class Model {
@Column
private int id;

@Id
private String name;

@OneToMany(fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
private List<Item> item;

public Model(){}

public Model(int id, String name, List<Item> item){
    this.id=id;
    this.name=name;
    this.item = item;
}
....


public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}
```

So my question is how do I display the attached models name in the table column "ModelName"

EDIT: I have attempted "this.model.getName()" as an attempt but this also did not work, I want to display the name and id if possible

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`new PropertyValueFactory<Item, String>("model")` will look for a method called `modelProperty` in your `Model` class. Use `StringProperty` so the `TableView` can recognize changes.
You can try

```
private StringProperty model;


public Model(int id, String name, List<Item> item){
    this.id=id;
    this.name=name;
    this.item = item;
    model = new StringProperty(getName()+" "+getId());
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
    model.set(getName()+" "+getId());
}

public StringProperty modelProperty() {
    return new StringProperty(getName()+" "+getId);
}
```

I cant test it by myself hope this helps

Comment: I used your idea, but I added new properties in my Item class and it would retrieve the models data. Thank you